# Injecting MailClient in while testing in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection, junit4

I have this classes that runs well when I run the app.

```
@Service("bookManager")
public class BookManagerImpl implements BookManager {

    private MailClient mailClient;

..

}

   @Service
public class MailClient {

    protected static final Logger looger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public MailClient(JavaMailSender mailSender, MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.mailContentBuilder = mailContentBuilder;
    }

    //TODO: in a properties
    public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom("nunito@calzada.com");
            messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
            messageHelper.setSubject("Sample mail subject");
            String content = mailContentBuilder.build(message);
            messageHelper.setText(content, true);
        };
        try {
            if (looger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                looger.debug("sending email to " + recipient);
            }
            mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            looger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I want to create a ServiceConfig for testing purposes but I don't know how to instantiate the class MailClient because has no default constructor and the constructor MailClient() is undefined

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public  SmsService smsService() {
        return new AWSSMSSender();
    }

    @Bean
    public  MailClient mailClient() {
        return new MailClient();
    }
}
```

Using the solution proposed:

```
 return new MailClient(null, null) {
        @Override
        public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    };
```

I got this error:

```
    No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: What is `MailClient`? What library does it come from?

Comment: Why do you specify an extra  @Autowired for the field mailSender? I think this is superfluous as you already inject the dependencies via constructor...

Comment: true, just to try. Without it I got the same error

Comment: Add an implementation of JavaMailSender to your ServiceConfig... Spring wants to autowire a dependency that it does not know... You can use the real class or a stub class for that...

Comment: to try, if you remove both @Autowired works in test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, send the email in tests (maybe with a test smpt server) or just simulate sending. In the second case you could subclass MailClient to do nothing in `prepareAndSend` and then use an instance of it.

```
   return new MailClient(null, null) {
        @Override
        public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user GreenMail for testing your email functionality in Spring Boot

You can refer this link :  http://dolszewski.com/spring/sending-html-mail-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf/

Answer (score 0):

You should use Stubbing.

The stubbing approach is easy to use and involves no extra dependencies for the unit test. The basic technique is to implement the collaborators as concrete classes which only exhibit the small part of the overall behaviour of the collaborator which is needed by the class under test. As an example consider the case where a service implementation is under test.